# .NET MAUI multibinding to XAML and view model

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, maui

In my .NET MAUI code-behind file for my MainPage, I would like to multi-bind to an element of my ViewModel as well as to the width and height of a grid defined in XAML.
The aim is to have the font in each grid cell auto-resize to the cell and also respects an "is text small" boolean.

The problem seems to be, that the binding to "ScreenGrid.Height" is not resolved correctly
 (the MultiValueConverter only receives an array filled with null).
ScreenGrid is defined in Xaml.
Resolving only the first of the 3 binding works as expected.
Setting the BindingContext of label to ScreenGrid does not work.

Are there any apparent mistakes or rules that I'm not aware of?

XAML:

```
<ContentPage [...]
    xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:Renderer.ViewModels"
    x:Class="Renderer.MainPage"
    x:DataType="viewmodels:CduViewModel">
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <!-- Screen -->
        <Grid x:Name="ScreenGrid"
            RowDefinitions="*, *, *, *, "
            ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,"
            [...]>
        </Grid>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage(ICduViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ViewModel = viewModel;

        AddScreenCells(); //Set up "Screen"
    }

    public void AddScreenCells()
    {
        var frameConverter = new Converters.FrameToFontSizeConverter();

        for (int row = 0; row < ScreenGrid.RowDefinitions.Count; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < ScreenGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count; col++)
            {
                //Label
                Label label = new()
                {
                    FontAutoScalingEnabled = false
                };

                label.SetBinding(Label.FontSizeProperty, new MultiBinding
                {
                    Bindings = new Collection<BindingBase>
                    {
                        //This binding works, if used seperately
                        new Binding($"{nameof(CduViewModel.Screen)}[{row}].{nameof(CduText.Sizes)}[{col}]"),
                    
                        //These bindings only work when setting the BindingContext to ScreenGrid, which kills the binding above.
                        new Binding($"{nameof(ScreenGrid)}.{nameof(ScreenGrid.Height)}"),
                        new Binding($"{nameof(ScreenGrid)}.{nameof(ScreenGrid.Width)}"),
                        },
                        Converter = frameConverter
                    });

                    ScreenGrid.Add(label, col, row);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **Add to question** all relevant declarations. Show declarations for `CduViewModel`, `ScreenGrid`, and `BindingContext`. First, as a test, lets get single bindings to work, for each Binding that you need. I assume from what you show, that in view's constructor you have `BindingContext = this;`. And that `CduViewModel` is a property in code behind? Also, verify that your `nameof`s each work when NOT inside a string. E.g. `var t = nameof(CduViewModel.Screen);` - does that code compile?

Comment: I've expanded on the MainPage code, to make it clear what's happening, hopefully.
The CduViewModel is added in the Constructor with dependency injection.

All the bindings work by themselfes, although binding to the ScreenGrid properties seems to require the BindingContext to be set to the Grid, which kills the binding to the viewmodel.

The strings by themselfes are what you would expect, e.g. "ScreenGrid.Height"

Comment: To make it clear `$"{nameof(ScreenGrid)}.{nameof(ScreenGrid.Height)}"`produces ScreenGrid.Height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set "source:" parameter of each ScreenGrid Binding:

```cs
new Binding($"{nameof(ScreenGrid)}.{nameof(ScreenGrid.Height)}",
        source: ScreenGrid)
```

This makes `ScreenGrid` the BindingContext of that Binding.

I did not test; maybe remove `{nameof(ScreenGrid)}.` from the path parameter.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you!
You were right, I also had to remove the `{nameof(ScreenGrid}.`part.

What confuses me a bit are the values, that are passed to the converter.
They are `-0.0416` and `-0.0769` for the Grid Width and Height respectively.
Is that a by-product of the grid being inside an AbsoluteLayout?

The code/converter itself produces the expected result, so this is just out of curiosity.

Comment: Those values are not what I would expect either. Can you check if the converter gets called again, with different values? Sometimes there is an (extra) early call, when some view doesn't yet have correct dimensions.

Comment: You were right, it goes through a few iterations with width and height at -1 respectively, (I guess once per grid cell) and then it settles for 370/422.
Thanks so much for your help!